# CASE WHEN for where clause that needs to loop over array

Tags: postgresql

I have a SELECT statement that needs to select records based on `asset_store_id`. `asset_store_id` is passed as either an empty array, or array of integers as `_src_asset_store` variable. If empty array, then all `asset_store_id` should be selected, otherwise, only the ids in the array should be selected.

Using CASE WHEN seems to be the way to go, but I can't seem to figure out how to add array to ELSE. My code looks like this:

```
    SELECT
        src.asset_store_id AS src_store
        ,src.asset_id AS src_asset_id
        ,dest.asset_id AS dest_asset_id
        ,dest.prior_asset_id AS dest_prior_asset_id
    FROM asset.assets AS src
    LEFT JOIN asset.assets AS dest
        ON dest.prior_asset_id = src.asset_id
    WHERE
        dest.asset_store_id = _dest_asset_store
        AND src.asset_store_id = CASE WHEN ARRAY_LENGTH(_src_asset_store, 1) = 0
                                    THEN src.asset_store_id
                                    ELSE IN(SELECT(UNNEST(_src_asset_store)))
                                END;
```

I have tried different variations for the ELSE statement including ELSE ANY(_src_asset_store), but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify the operation both inside and outside the case (= outside, IN inside in one branch).  If you want different operations, put the whole comparison in each branch of the CASE and have it return boolean:

```
AND CASE WHEN ARRAY_LENGTH(_src_asset_store, 1) = 0
    THEN true
    ELSE src.asset_store_id IN(SELECT(UNNEST(_src_asset_store)))
END;
```

Or don't use a CASE at all

```
AND (ARRAY_LENGTH(_src_asset_store, 1) = 0 or src.asset_store_id IN(SELECT(UNNEST(_src_asset_store))) )
```

But I would also avoid the UNNEST:

```
AND (ARRAY_LENGTH(_src_asset_store, 1) = 0 or ARRAY[src.asset_store_id] && _src_asset_store )
```

Comment: `src.asset_store_id IN(SELECT(UNNEST(_src_asset_store)))` can be simplified to `src.asset_store_id = ANY (_src_asset_store)`